# Exclude files from Java .properties file

Tags: java, properties

I have a *.properties* file I'm using to specify Java classes I'd like to feed to a Checkstyle tool to check for whether Javadoc exists in a class. Suppose in the directory *foo* I have the following directories:

- a1
- a2
- a3
- a4
- B

My end goal is to specify *a1...a4* as one property and *B* as another.

Currently, I'm having to specify each directory, like the following:

```
javadoc.classes.a=\
    foo/a1/**/*.java,\
    foo/a2/**/*.java,\
    foo/a3/**/*.java,\
    foo/a4/**/*.java

javadoc.classes.b=\
    foo/B/**/*.java
```

Is there a way I can specify *javadoc.classes.a* by simply stating all classes in directory *foo* except for those residing in *foo/B*? For example:

```
javadoc.class.a=\
    foo/**/*.java,\
    (exclude foo/B here)
```

For reference, I looked in Oracle's docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html), but did not find an answer to my question. Is this scenario I've outlined possible, by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java properties file is like a persisted Hastable. If you look into the documentation for Properties class you will see that it extends a HashTable.
So essentially all you are doing is storing and retrieving Strings.

You cannot use regular expressions as file names, as they would be retrieved in your program as Strings and that would not do any good.

But you can feed them to a pattern matcher class that would use Java's Pattern and Matcher classes to traverse your file system or a specific directory to find any matching file.

Hope this helps!